# Read user authorization groups from Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory

In our system we are reading user security groups from an Active Directory in two slightly different ways. In one case the list of groups returned by the AD is missing the domain local groups. The response from GetAuthorizationGroups () is dependent on the used PrincipalContext. In the failing scenarios GetAuthorizationGroups() will only return global groups. The result is missing all domain local groups from the AD. Can anyone please explain why?

Failing solution:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "our.domain.net");

var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, "userB");

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

In this case the process is executed by “UserA”. “UserA” is a member of the domain “our.domain.net”. “UserA” is the very same user as the specifically identified user in the working solution. The PrincipalContext should because of that be identical to the PrincipalContext in the working solution. The response from GetAuthorizationGroups() in this solution miss domain local groups from the AD.

Working solution:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "our.domain.net", "UserA", "PasswordA");

var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.UserPrincipalName, "userB");

PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = userPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups();
```

In this case the calling user is identified specifically by use name and password when creating the Principal Context. In this case the AD returns all the groups that the user is a member of. This is the behavior I would like to see from the failing solution as well. In some cases I do not have the user password of UserA and of that reason the Working solution is not an option.

Please help me understand why the failing solution does not return all the groups that the user is a member of.

Comment: Do you have more than one domain?  What OS are you on?  It may be related to UAC.  I would try turning off the UAC and try again (remember to restart the computer after you turn off the UAC).  FYI, ValidateCredentials() doesn't help you do the GetAuthorizationGroups() in case you thought it does

Comment: Thanks for your response Harvey.

The problems were found during system test in our test lab. The test system consist of one single domain and multiple domain controllers. The code in the problem description is executed by a Windows 2003 server. Before release of our product we will have to support multiple domains and Windows 2008 server as well.

I have asked our windows server installation guru to do some experiments with the UAC. He mumbled something about “Isn’t that a 2008 feature”. He was going to look into it anyway. I will have his response posted shortly.

Best regards, Gunnar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We finally found the problem. It turned out not to be a coding problem at all. The strange behaviour was caused by an erronious Domain Level in the Active Directory.

Domain Level had to be set to "2003 functional level"

Now it all works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

*"It misses domain local groups from the AD"* because you are probably iterating the resulting `groups` with `foreach` loop and you are getting `NoMatchingPrincipalException` exception for one of the groups that the user doesnt have read access and at that point it stops iterating, failing to get the rest of the groups.

As a solution you may use the following iterator (the code behind the `foreach` structure) to get all the rest of the groups:

```
var enumerator = groups.GetEnumerator();                
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
    try
    {
        var e = enumerator.Current;
        listView1.Items.Add(e.Name);
    }
    catch (NoMatchingPrincipalException)
    {
    }
}
```