# Active Directory UserPrinciple GetAuthorizationGroups does not return local groups

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices, userprincipal

We have an authorisation routine written using .Net `DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` namespace and `(UserPrinciple).GetAuthorizationGroups()`  which is nicely returning nested global security groups for a user.

We have one customer who say they use "Microsoft ADGLP method of role-based access control" and that they would like to return local groups as well.

Is this possible as an option / extension of what we are doing already?

Comment: I have the same problem, so I'll watch this thread carefully. But in my search I also found this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519033/read-user-authorization-groups-from-active-directory